# Applying a predicate with anyMatch() on a map keyset stream and returning some result when the predicate is false

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have a class *Parcelle* with three attributes *num* and *nature* and *autre_nature*. and a list of Parcelle *listParcelles*. I am experiencing with Java 8 Streams, and what I would like to achieve is to group by num and return the *Parcelle* which has both non null *nature* and *autre_nature* attributes, otherwise just return one Parcelle from the group at random.

```
Example :   
Input:   

    ligneParcelles[[num=1,nature=TC,autre_nature=TCC],  
                   [num=1,nature=TC,autre_nature=null],
                   [num=2,nature=TC,autre_nature=null],
                   [num=3,nature=TC,autre_nature=null],
                   [num=3,nature=Alpha,autre_nature=null],
                   [num=4,nature=TC,autre_nature=TC]
                   [num=4,nature=TC,autre_nature=null]]
Output :   
    ligneParcelles [[num=1,nature=TC,autre_nature=TCC],  
                   [num=2,nature=TC,autre_nature=null],
                   [num=3,nature=Alpha,autre_nature=null],
                   [num=4,nature=TC,autre_nature=TC]]
```

for grouping I used the following code :

```
Map<String, List<Parcelle>> mapLignesParcelles = listParcelles.stream()                                                    

          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(lp->lp.getNum()+""));
```

but I am not sure what to use in order to get the final result, I can stream *mapLignesParcelles* keyset and I think of anymatch with a predicate `lp.getNature()!=null && lp.getAutre_Nature() !=null` but How can I express the fact to return any element when the predicate does not hold ?

Comment: what if there are more matches for `lp.getNature()!=null && lp.getAutre_Nature() !=null` for a single `num`?

Comment: @Eugene just return the first with findFirst() as in Andrew's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a mapping of each `Num` to a single `Parcelle` in the form of `Map<String, Parcelle>` instead of a `List` as in `groupingBy`. One way is to use `toMap` while collecting as:

```
Map<String, Parcelle> output = listParcelles.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.getNum() + "", a -> a,
                (parcelle1, parcelle2) -> parcelle1.getNature() != null
                        && parcelle1.getAutre_nature() != null ? parcelle1 : parcelle2));
```

Another from the way ahead of grouping could be as:

```
Map<String, Parcelle> output = mapLignesParcelles.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()
                .stream()
                .filter(lp -> lp.getNature() != null && lp.getAutre_nature() != null)
                .findAny()
                .orElse(e.getValue().get(new Random().nextInt(e.getValue().size())))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: I used the first method and it worked, toMap method on Collectors class is just what I needed with the mergerFunction parameter

Answer (score 2):

```
stream
    .filter(yourCondition)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(randomlySelectedObject);
```

You have a `stream`, you filter it by your condition, you try to get the first element that matches the criterion, you return it if found, otherwise you return `randomlySelectedObject`.

Comment: but the stream after the filter operation does not contain any element when the predicate is false, how will  that randomlySelectedObject operate ?

Comment: @mounaim the stream doesn't, but the original collection (which you built the stream upon) does

Comment: @mounaim I can't make it more clear unless you provide a complete snippet. I have no idea what you did to move from Input to Output, but I am pretty sure it's not what the snippet you mentioned does